# Export Azure App Service Certificate as .pfx on Mac

Tags: azure, powershell

What is the easiest way to export an Azure App Service Certificate on Mac?
All results seem to point to Powershell - I have attempted to install Powershell on Mac via PowerShell Core, though I have experienced a large amount of authentication issues, namely with the Connect-AzureRmAccount command:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would clearly help alot if you could provide the code that you are running and that is throwing the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: It is simply Connect-AzureRmAccount, which prompts the user to enter a code in the browser and log into an Office365 account.

Comment: Same here, I read on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/02/24/creating-a-local-pfx-copy-of-app-service-certificate/ that when using Mac you can use the Cloud Shell directly within Azure portal, but not saying how and when copy-paste it just gives a lot of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

**1. Install Powershell with brew:**

```
brew cask install powershell
```

**2. Verify that your install is working properly:**

```
pwsh
```

**3. Execute the powershell script found here:** https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/12/export-an-azure-app-service-certificate-pfx-powershell/